# Error: 403 Forbidden while pushing/pulling images to/from docker

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am using **docker server version : 1.10.3**  with docker distribution installed on **RHEL 7.2** 
The issue i am facing is an intermittent one. Some times the push/pull commands works and some times they throw below error:

```
Pulling repository test.a.b.c.com/hello-world
Error: Status 403 trying to pull repository hello-world: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>403 Forbidden</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Forbidden</h1>\n<p>You don't have permission to access /v1/repositories/hello-world/images\non this server.<br />\n</p>\n</body></html>\n"
```

The output of  " **sudo service docker status**" is:

```
Aug 15 11:04:48 server forward-journal[6535]: time="2016-08-15T11:04:48.866644712+02:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.22/images/create returned error: invalid reference format"
Aug 15 21:40:05 server forward-journal[6535]: time="2016-08-15T21:40:05.558387849+02:00" level=info msg="{Action=build, LoginUID=4294967295, PID=17431}"
Aug 15 21:40:23 server forward-journal[6535]: time="2016-08-15T21:40:23.346912366+02:00" level=info msg="{Action=push, LoginUID=4294967295, PID=17452}"
Aug 15 21:40:23 server forward-journal[6535]: time="2016-08-15T21:40:23.426768722+02:00" level=error msg="Upload failed: Error parsing HTTP response: unexpected end of JSON input: \"\""
Aug 15 21:40:23 server forward-journal[6535]: time="2016-08-15T21:40:23.428789638+02:00" level=error msg="Upload failed: Error parsing HTTP response: unexpected end of JSON input: \"\""
Aug 15 22:36:05 server forward-journal[6535]: time="2016-08-15T22:36:05.122054012+02:00" level=info msg="{Action=build, LoginUID=4294967295, PID=22228}"
Aug 15 22:36:16 server forward-journal[6535]: time="2016-08-15T22:36:16.022509441+02:00" level=info msg="{Action=push, LoginUID=4294967295, PID=22247}"
Aug 16 07:17:45 server forward-journal[6535]: time="2016-08-16T07:17:45.608893675+02:00" level=info msg="{Action=create, Username=test, LoginUID=877601153, PID=978}"
Aug 16 07:18:24 server forward-journal[6535]: time="2016-08-  16T07:18:24.768737515+02:00" level=info msg="{Action=push, Username=test, LoginUID=877601153, PID=1081}"
Aug 16 07:20:15 server forward-journal[6535]: time="2016-08-16T07:20:15.546273448+02:00" level=info msg="{Action=create, Username=test, LoginUID=877601153, PID=1273}"
```

Could anyone explain why is it so?  Why do I get 403 forbidden issue even though I have rights. 
 
Why it works sometimes and doesn't sometimes?

Answer (score 0):

I definitely believe this is a security feature to prevent [DoS / DDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attacks or similars when lot of concurrent pulls are executed from the same `IP` address.

We had a similar issue today, while attending a nice course on [`containers & HPC`](https://imperialcollegelondon.github.io/2020-07-13-Containers-Online/) and everybody was pulling from https://singularity-hub.org the same `hello-world` image from the same cluster, through:

```
singularity pull hello-world.sif shub://vsoch/hello-world
```

the following error message appeared to most of attendants:

```
FATAL:   While pulling shub image: failed to get manifest for: shub://vsoch/hello-world: 403 Forbidden
```

while it disappeared minutes later.