# failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.V0

Tags: python, django, docker

I am pretty new to Docker and trying to build docker image with plain python django ,I have this error message

```
[+] Building 3.0s (3/3) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.7s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 224B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.9s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9                                                1.7s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: unexpected status code [manifests 3.9]: 403 Forbidden
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /code
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system
COPY . /code/
```

Comment: Can you run a `docker pull python:3.9`? Is there a proxy on your network limiting external access?

Comment: @BMitch not work !! I live in syria but I run psiphion program to solve proxy problem but don't work can help me?

Comment: Are you running into Docker Hub's rate limits?  If you have a Docker Hub account, does logging into it help?  (See also [Error: 403 Forbidden while pushing/pulling images to/from docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38969126/error-403-forbidden-while-pushing-pulling-images-to-from-docker).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syria is on the [embargoed county list](https://www.tradecompliance.pitt.edu/embargoed-and-sanctioned-countries). It's US government policy, not much we can do.  From the [Docker ToS](https://www.docker.com/legal/docker-terms-service):

> 20.8 You understand that the Service is subject to United States export controls administered by the U.S. Department of Commerce and the United States Department of Treasury Office of Foreign Assets Control. You acknowledge and agrees that the Service and any User Content or Third Party Content accessed by you shall not be used, transferred or otherwise exported or re-exported to countries as to which the United States, maintains an embargo (collectively, "Embargoed Countries") ...

Answer (score 2):

For a similar case where using the AWS own Deep learning images as docker base image, having this before build step solved the 403 issue:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
export COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error:

> failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB
> definition: unexpected status code [manifests 14]: 500 Internal Server
> Error

Then you can proceed by [overriding the default frontend](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#overriding-default-frontends).

Modify your Dockerfile by adding a line at the top row that specifies the syntax/frontend-image. Like so:

```
#syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
```

This is how my entire Dockerfile looks like now:

```
#syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14 

# Copy function code
COPY app.js ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Set the CMD to your handler
CMD ["app.handler"]
```